# Will Customs in India figure out that I have two laptops?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, import-taxes

I am going back to India soon from the US. Can I take a laptop in my carry-on luggage and another laptop in my checked baggage, so that I don't have to pay customs duty for either of the laptops? Will they ever figure out that I have two laptops? Does Indian Customs check the *combined* luggage of every person to see how much electronic goods they are carrying?

In case, a laptop is not allowed can I carry *2* NVMe SSDs *and* a RAM module in my checked baggage, without them complaining?

Comment: Great. Now anyone who answers risks being tried for conspiracy under Indian jurisdiction. I'll pass.

Comment: I have a friend interning with me, who did the same last year and paid no duties. I used to think Lithium batteries were not allowed in checked baggage. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I take two laptops to India from United States? One bought in India and one in US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12975/can-i-take-two-laptops-to-india-from-united-states-one-bought-in-india-and-one) (see the second answer)

Comment: Are you seriously asking for help in smuggling two laptops and/or hard drives in to India?

Comment: I do not know for sure, but I'd be very surprised if Indian customs laws only applied to one of hand luggage and checked luggage

Comment: I've no experience with India so I won't post this as an answer but have previously flown to Israel with 2 laptops. When asked at customs why I have 2 laptops I just said one's a business laptop and one's for personal use and was waved through without issue. (At the time I was registered as a self employed person so would have had proof of business use if pushed).

Answer (score 6):

> Can I take a laptop in my carry-on luggage and another laptop in my checked baggage, so that I don't have to pay customs duty for either of the laptops?

## No

The duty free allowances are per person, not per suitcase.

It doesn't matter if one device is packed in your carry on luggage and another in a checked bag, you have to declare the contents / value of your combined baggage.

> Does Indian Customs check the combined luggage of every person to see how much electronic goods they are carrying?

Probably not of *every* person and not all the time.

Like many customs authorities they depend  on passengers making their own customs declaration and self-assessment and they have a "Green channel" for passengers to that not have dutiable goods and a "Red Channel" for passengers that do.

That system gets enforced by "random" more thorough checks and the fact that passengers getting caught  walking through the Green Channel with dutiable/prohibited goods
are liable to prosecution/ penalty and confiscation of goods.

Comment: Let's make it clear that when one is caught, it will usually cost a lot more than if one declared things up front, though the exact details can vary substantially.

Comment: +1 Every time I've been through a Red/Green customs system I've had all my luggage with me, checked and carry-on. When they stop someone they look at the passenger and all their luggage as a unit.

Answer (score 3):

As far as customs is concerned, there is no difference between checked baggage and carry-on baggage -- you go through customs *after* collecting your checked baggage. So your question about combined luggage makes no sense.