# Can I carry One office laptop, one personal laptop and one Surface tablet?

Tags: india, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens

I am returning from US to Bangalore.
I was travelling on B1 Visa.
While going to US, I was carrying one Laptop from Office. I have ID for this Laptop as well.

In US I have purchased a Laptop ($399) and one Surface Tablet($199).
Will I be charged in the customs?
If yes, How much?

Comment: No it is not. Cos I have a Surface Tab as well.

Comment: see also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/can-i-take-both-a-laptop-and-a-tablet-in-my-carry-on-bag-when-going-to-india