# How many mobile phones can I bring to India?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india

I am traveling from the UK to Delhi and I am bringing 4 phones with me + mine the rest are for friends.  These phones are all used so will this be an issue in bringing them through customs?

Comment: @user568458 That question explains how to compute one's duty free allowance and is regarded as our canonical on importing electronic goods in India.

Answer (score 6):

As per the [Indian customs rules](http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason22may2013.pdf):

[image: Duty free allowance]

There *is* [a limit on the number of laptops you can bring back](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10990/108), but none for mobile phones. That would fall under the standard limit of INR 35,000 / INR 15,000 depending on how many days you were away from India as shown in the table above.

You haven't mentioned the make of the phones. Ideally, you'll need receipts to prove what the original purchase price was so that depreciation can be calculated, or "used" price was. I'm guessing they'll bother if, say, it was an iPhone as compared to a brick Nokia phone.