# In a trip through many countries, might I pay duty several times on things I bought in the first country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, import-taxes

I have a question re shopping/customs at each entry on a multi stopover trip.

Itinerary:
- Australia to China (5 days)
- China to India (5 days)
- India to Australia ( Connecting flights via China but no stopover)

If I buy things in China, stopover, do I have to pay duties and taxes in India as well as when I return to Australia? In general would I have to pay in every country of the trip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no material difference between a stopover and a normal visit. When you arrive in India, Indian customs rules apply regardless of whether you bought the stuff in China or in Australia or whether you arrive via China or directly from Australia.

Same thing if you return to Australia: Australian custom rules apply regardless whether you bought the stuff in India or China.

Comment: Actually, you *could* get an ATA Carnet or Customs bond to certify that the goods will be reexported from India.  This is highly unlikely to be worth the massive hassle entailed though. https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/27595/1893

Comment: While this is true, those customs rules generally refer specifically only to things you intend to leave in the country, exempting things you owned on arrival and are taking away (eg your clothes, phone, laptop, suitcase...) Depending on what the items are and how expensive they are, there may be no issue.