# Bringing mobile bought in US to india

Tags: customs-and-immigration, cellphones

I have bought a mobile through a friend in the US. What is the best way to get it to India without getting into trouble while departure from US and on arrival to India (customs)?

Comment: Avoiding customs is not legal.

Comment: will i get into trouble if i say its an Indian mobile and i took it with me and carry it in the hand hag..?

Comment: If you declare it to Indian Customs and pay the tax promptly you won't get into trouble. :)

Comment: Probably not. But evading the law is off-topic on this website. If you do want to take it though, there are some tips [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31146/can-we-carry-three-new-smart-phones-in-hand-luggage-to-india/31206#31206). Also, always remember, you cannot be scared and daring at the same time. Choose one, be safe and pay the duty.

Comment: thank u..i ll probably take the safe route..daring route was just an after thought..how much is the duty for mobiles sir..?my bill price is 375$..since i am paying the duty i can have it packed right..?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting around the law

Comment: @user18556 This may be of assistance - http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason11June2014.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Just carry it with you. You are allowed to carry personal items, such as phones, with you from one country to another.

If it is still new in the box, it might raise flags that you're importing it, rather than carrying it as a personal phone, in which case you may be required to pay import duties.