# Carrying 2 laptops and 2 Mobiles to Chennai Airport from Sydney on return back to India

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, duty-free

I travelled from Chennai to Sydney, Australia last year in July. I brought a smartphone and personal laptop with me while leaving to Australia and didn’t declare them as they are for my personal use. I have now purchased an iPhone and a MacBook here in Sydney as I am leaving back to India in a few days. Could someone please let me know if there will be any customs cost incurred on carrying these two laptops and two mobile phones in carriage luggage.

Please suggest if there is any way that I can manipulate this situation to get rid of the customs.

Comment: So...you want to 'manipulate' to 'get rid of customs' - ie circumvent the law?

Comment: ARE the new ones for personal use, eg have you opened the boxes and used them?

Comment: Related: [How much electronics and other valuables can I bring duty-free when going to India?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10990/26)