# How much quantity of saffron can be carried to India?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india

I will be traveling from Sharjah, how much saffron is permissible to carry in the main luggage?

Comment: As explained in [How much electronics and other valuables can I bring duty-free when going to India?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-much-electronics-and-other-valuables-can-i-bring-duty-free-when-going-to-ind) you can carry up to your duty-free allowance, and pay import duty on the excess. Because it is a plant product you must declare it, even if it is less than the duty-free allowance. If you don't declare it, you could be fined or even arrested, but if you do declare it there is no such penalty (other than paying the duty).

Comment: It is like trying to smuggle opium into Afganistan, why would you bring saffron to India? Buy as much as you want in Kashmir and it is one of the best in the world.