# Carrying two laptops (one personal and one for work) to India

Tags: passports, india

Is it okay to carry two laptops (one personal and one for work) from Sweden to India (Bangalore International Airport)?

Comment: Check this link - http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-much-electronics-and-other-valuables-can-i-bring-duty-free-when-going-to-ind?noredirect=1&lq=1. Personally from my experience, I have carried two laptops across many airlines across many countries (inclusive of Europe and Asia). I was never questioned. It was not very comfortable carrying them but I was never stopped because of it. But maybe I got lucky.

Comment: Sorry @HeidelBerGensis. My edit overwrote your tag changes. Perhaps you should put them through again?

Answer (score 0):

Why should there be any issues? You'd not expect trouble because you bring two pairs of shoes either.

Aside from potential weight limits, and potential *explicit* restrictions from an airline (which I have never seen), you can bring as many laptops (and iPhones, etc.) as you want.

Comment: India has some weird customs rules for electronics, beyond what is the international "norm".

Comment: Probably _customs_ issues - they assume that you are planning to sell the extras, so you will need convincing proof they are yours and not for selling.