# What are the restrictions regarding bringing back items into the United States, bought in India?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, shopping, import-taxes

I am a US citizen planning to travel to India and I hear the shopping there is quite fair. In particular the electronics. I want to get a few items to bring back home with me. So are there any restrictions? In addition to this, I am not aware of the taxation rules regarding imports.

Comment: You are a US citizen?

Comment: Yes, US citizen flying out of LAX

Comment: With the number of people [asking about bringing stuff the other way](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-much-electronics-and-other-valuables-can-i-bring-duty-free-when-going-to-ind), I'm surprised that you would want to *purchase* electronics in India.

Comment: @PeterM I don't think citizenship matters, only residency.

Comment: @GregHewgill I have heard that electronics are cheaper in India compared to the united states. A possible reason being the proximity to the manufacturer. Otherwise, I am not sure why this is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Straight from the source:

- [U.S. Customs and Border Protection  Duty Free Exemptions](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/454/~/duty-free-exemption,-gifts)

> If you are a U.S. resident returning from a foreign country with goods acquired abroad in your possession after a stay of 48-hours or more, you may be eligible for a personal duty-free exemption. If you are returning from Mexico, the 48-hour rule does not apply. The personal exemption you are eligible for depends on the country you are returning from.
>
> For instance, if you are returning from countries other than the Caribbean countries or U.S. insular possession you are entitled to an $800 duty-free exemption and the next $1,000 worth of the goods you purchased is subject to a flat rate of 3%. If the value exceeds $1,800, the remaining duty will be determined based on duty rates in the harmonized tariff schedule, which are generally between 0-10% (except for clothing and textiles, which can be much higher, up to 25%).
>
> If you are returning from a U.S. insular possession (i.e. U.S. Virgin Islands or Guam) you are entitled to a $1,600 duty-free exemption and the next $1,000 worth of the goods you purchased is subject to a flat rate of 1.5%.
>
> If you are returning from a foreign country other than Mexico and were not there for a total of 48 hours you are entitled to a $200 duty-free exemption and the next $1,000 worth of the goods you purchased is subject to a flat rate of 3%. If the value of your goods exceeds $1,200, the remaining duty will be determined based on duty rates in the Harmonized Tariff Schedule.

### Resident

"Resident" here basically means anyone who is not on a visitor's visa, and includes not only citizens and permanent residents (obviously) but also students (F1 visa holders), H1B visa holders etc.

### Counterfeit goods

As asked in the comments, there are restrictions on importing counterfeit goods, but individuals are allowed to bring single instances of a counterfeit item so long as it is for personal use.  So importing one knock-off Prada bag is fine, bringing two more for your friends is not (even if the counterfeit brands are different on each.)  Full details are to be found here [Customs Directive 2310-11A](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/2310-11a_3.pdf) .

Comment: @handroski No restrictions on what you can bring back (food etc not withstanding), but certainly you have to pay duty over and above a certain amount.

Comment: @handroski Well there are some restrictions on amounts of alcohol and tobbacco and of course  agricultural/fresh food restrictions which are imposed by the USDA.

Comment: Aren't there restrictions on counterfeits as well? Like if you buy a knock-off name brand watch or purse.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Counterfeit goods are OK for personal use only https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/2310-11a_3.pdf

Comment: @PeterM Thanks for the link. I've updated the answer since that link speaks more explicitly to the personal use issue.