# Gold Jewelry - Any limit?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, duty-free

I have bought my fiance several gold jewelry over 2 years (I would estimate total of 10k). Most of this was bought back in January 2020. It is all a gift, she has all the receipts. Does she need to declare it when she comes to the US? Also can she wear it and bring it OR does she need to put it in the carry on?

Comment: It does not matter if she wears it or puts it in carry on, when she uses the 'I have something to declare' option, they will check it out whether in the bag or on the body. I do not know how much you can bring into the US, but I think it is much less than 10K $US.

Comment: What are the circumstances of the entry to the US? Is it purely for a tourist visit and will be leaving again? Is your fiance moving there?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74297/what-are-the-restrictions-regarding-bringing-back-items-into-the-united-states/74300?r=SearchResults#74300

Comment: There are for sure people that travel and wear millions on their hands and ears, like filmstars. I doubt anyone will even think to ask about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you bought your girlfriend jewelry while she was living abroad, then it is her personal possession. If she comes to the US for a visit she is permitted to bring them with her, just as if she had bought them herself, as long as she intends to take them home with her again. There is no limit on the value, or at least if there is it is well above $10K.

The only issue with that is if customs don't believe that the jewelry is genuinely her personal possessions, and that she intends to import them. (The receipts don't help, as they prove only that she bought them, not that she does not intend to resell them.) This doesn't happen often, as plenty of people bring jewelry with them and take it away when they leave. In some cases it may be worth declaring the jewelry and explicitly stating they are personal possessions, rather than having customs search her and then accusing her of illegally importing. She shouldn't have to pay duty if her story is accepted.

If your girlfriend is moving to the US permanently the process is different, but she should still be allowed to import her personal possessions duty free. Further questions about that should be asked on our Expatriates site.