# Will I owe customs duty on Xbox One X while going to India?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, import-taxes

I have recently bought an Xbox One X which cost around 534 USD including taxes. I wish to take it with me to India (Hyderabad). But I am worried about the duty imposed on it, which might be more than half the price of the product.

I have read in some forums that the duty is applicable on items only exceeding 35000 INR (540 USD).

Is it true? If it is true, can I take it along with the packing box that it came with? Do I have to carry the invoice along with me?

Is there a proper and better way to avoid customs on my used XBox One X? What do I need to keep in mind? How do I need to pack it in my luggage? How do I need to prepare for the worst as well?

Comment: You have duty-free allowance of 45,000 INR - but it is combined, not per-item. Please see this answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-much-electronics-and-other-valuables-can-i-bring-duty-free-when-going-to-ind

Comment: Would you be ok taking it back with you without the box? Maybe then it can be treated as second hand and/or not for commercial purpose. If needed, you could ship the packaging separately via surface mail, before you leave. Disclaimer: I'm not knowledgeable about these, but presenting ideas and exploring options.

Comment: Are you asking us to advise you how to break the law? I don't think that is what this forum is here for.

Comment: When you say "Take it to India", do you mean that you will be visiting India with the Xbox for a short time and taking the Xbox out of India when you leave, or that you live in India (or will be living in India) and the Xbox will be in India on a roughly permanent basis? These two situations are very different. Most countries don't care very much about the value of items that visitors temporarily bring into the country, but care a lot about the value of items that are being permanently imported.

Comment: People might take to your question better if you rephrase to "Will I owe a duty on my Xbox?"

Answer (score 47):

> How do I avoid Customs Duty...

You don't. If you're carrying dutiable goods and attempt to avoid duty it's smuggling. If you're caught expect some or all of a fine; confiscation of the items; a criminal record; imprisonment. That's your 'worst case'.

The good news is that you're probably not liable for duty on your XBox One X. According to the [rules](http://www.cbec.gov.in/resources/htdocs-cbec/baggage-rules.pdf) published by the Indian Central Board of Excise & Customs you're entitled to import

> (a) used personal effects and travel souvenirs; and
>
> (b) articles other
> than those mentioned in Annexure-I<sup>*</sup>, **up to the value of fifty thousand**
> **rupees** if these are carried on the person or in the accompanied
> baggage of the passenger:

<sup>(My emphasis)</sup>

<sup>*</sup> Annexure 1 covers guns, ammunition, cigarettes, alcohol, gold & silver and flat panel televisions.

This document was published in April 2016 - I haven't found a later version.

Note that the allowance is given on, and duty charged on, the 'assessed value' of the item, which may differ from the invoiced value.

If in doubt, take the red channel at customs and declare the item. If no duty is payable you shouldn't be charged and you go on your way. If duty is payable you pay it and go on your way. It's possible that a friendly customs officer may grant leniency if the duty amount is relatively small and let you through anyway. (It's happened to me at UK customs). Even if you end up paying a significant amount of import duty your import is legal and you're safe. This is definitely the way to go.

Next time, consider the import restrictions *before* buying abroad!

Comment: What I want to know is how flat panel televisions end up lumped in with smokes, guns, booze, and untraceable currency?

Comment: @J...Someone in Indian Customs must've been a big fan of Black Sabbath's "TV Crimes". :) https://youtu.be/KdWnr_zxvnM

Comment: @J... They're all things people try to smuggle in because they have high import duties levied on them by the Indian government.

Comment: I learned on Marketplace the other day that "tax avoidance" isn't illegal, but "tax *evasion*" is.

Comment: @Jay Sure, but lots of things have high duties... watches, gizmos, ambergris, whatever.  Who manages to smuggle a flat screen TV through customs?  It's not exactly inconspicuous...