# Carrying television in flight from Germany to India

Tags: airports, india, germany, bookings

I have searched on the airline websites, but however have not found a concrete answer to my question which is: if I were to take my 55" TV along with me from Germany to India, will the airlines allow this as a checked luggage? If yes, how much would the cost for such a transport be.

Hope someone can throw some light on this.

Comment: Can you pack it well enough to survive being thrown around with the suitcases? If yes, it seems a matter of weight and dimensions.

Comment: As an aside, it appears India charges 36.05% duty on all flat-screen televisions imported there, and there is no exemption.

Comment: Also highly relevant: [Will I owe customs duty on Xbox One X while going to India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/104987/11491)

Answer (score 2):

I took an example of [this Samsung model](http://www.samsung.com/us/video/tvs/UN55C7000WFXZA-specs), which has shipping dimensions of 62.4" x 35.4" x 7.9" and a shipping weight of 67.7 lbs.

Then taking an example of a flight from Germany to India, say from Frankfurt to Delhi.

This route is serviced by Lufthansa flight 760 and Air India flight 120.

For Lufthansa, on their [website](http://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Free-baggage-rules):

> The maximum size per piece of baggage, regardless of class, is 158 cm
>   (width + height + depth).

For Air India, the same rules apply.

The TV doesn't match these rules, as its clearly outside the bounds of what can be checked in; this means it will have be shipped as oversized cargo.