# 2 laptops (1 professional and 1 personal ) and 1 iPad

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, import-taxes

I am planning to travel to India (Delhi airport) from the United States. I want to take my 2 laptops (1 personal and 1 professional) as well as my tablet (iPad). Am I allowed to take 3 gadgets in my backpack or in my check-in bag? I think I am allowed to take only 2 computers. Will Customs consider my iPad as a computer?

Comment: On a related note, whether you will be allowed to have 3 gadgets in your backpack and whether you will need to pay customs are completely different matters - the former is up to the TSA and the airline. As long as your backpack's weight is below the limit of the carrier and the batteries are properly secured and not about the airline's limit in terms of capacity, you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to take as many electronic items in your backpack as you want through security, you just have to take them all out for the TSA check.
The most important question is if you have to declare them and/or pay import taxes at customs.

As Ankur Banerjee states in his [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-much-electronics-and-other-valuables-can-i-bring-duty-free-when-going-to-ind) here on SE, you can bring one personal computer. so the second one will definitely be an issue. For the iPad, it's more difficult, because it's not defined, if it counts as a computer.