# Taking a Desktop PC and 21" Monitor from Abu Dhabi to India (Bangalore)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, airport-security

I'm planning to take my used mini Lenovo tower desktop computer & its 21" monitor from Abu Dhabi to india (Bangalore.)

Should I pack it in its original company boxes or should I pack both monitor and pc inside a carton box?

Should I have to pay customs? I don't have the original bill.

Edited
If not packed on original boxes is this going to be flagged as suspicious like explosive upon departure ? or during the arrival when unoriginal box passes through x-ray custom will mark it or investigate ? In order to avoid all these embarrassing situations what's the right way.

Comment: For your doubt about customs, this is already answered here, see: [How much electronics and other valuables can I bring duty-free when going to India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10990/3221)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much electronics and other valuables can I bring duty-free when going to India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-much-electronics-and-other-valuables-can-i-bring-duty-free-when-going-to-ind)

Comment: @gparyani There are multiple questions here. The others need to be answered as well.

Comment: @MichaelHampton If that's the case, this should be marked "too broad"; the question should only ask one question.

Comment: @gparyani Or you could just refer the user to the question which was already answered, and then answer his other question.

Comment: The duty question has already been answered. As for packing, I can't believe it matters whether they're in the original boxes or not. The issue is whether you can adequately protect them.