# Possible issues when carrying multiple laptops/phones from India to Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, india

[This questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-much-electronics-and-other-valuables-can-i-bring-duty-free-when-going-to-ind) discusses the rules around how many laptops one can bring to India, but I was wondering if there are any rules about outgoing travel *from* India. [I found this document](https://www.cbic.gov.in/resources/htdocs-cbec/guide_for_travellers/GUIDE_FOR_TRAVELLERS_v5.pdf) which, again, doesn't have any information about departing passengers.

As far as I know, Canada does not have any rules about how many laptops or phones I bring with me, but should I be worried about anything with customs while *leaving* India?

I plan on carrying 2 laptops (Work and Personal), and 3 phones. I'm a university student doing an internship, so explaining the "work" laptop might be difficult, and I'm not sure how I can prove that it is a work laptop if I'm asked. I don't have receipts for most of these devices since they're all pretty old.

To clarify, all devices are for personal/work use. I'm an Indian Citizen with a Canadian Student/Work visa.

Comment: Get a letter from your employer to state that the laptop belongs to them and you have permission to remove it from the country

Comment: @Midavalo to be clear, the internship is for a Canadian company and I am flying from India to Canada. Would the Indian authorities have any authority to charge duty/stop me from carrying a laptop to Canada? That is still good advice though, I'll see if I can do that (though I probably should have done that while travelling from Canada to India)

Comment: Realistically, nobody will ask about two laptops; that’s very common. Three phones might make someone wonder, but if you don’t put them in plain view, nobody will ever know or care. It’s not smuggling; it’s only illegal if you plan to sell them in the country.

Comment: @Aganju Even if it's legal to bring them into the country, customs law will be violated if the traveler brings them in _without declaring them_.