# Can I bring unboxed Intel Core i9 13900k from India to USA?

Tags: usa, india

How can I bring it without paying any custom/IGST? I am Indian origin US citizen, and it cost 524$

Comment: bringing it from where to where?

Comment: @Hilmar IGST is an Indian term, so I would believe it's from the US to India

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much electronics and other valuables can I bring duty-free when going to India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-much-electronics-and-other-valuables-can-i-bring-duty-free-when-going-to-ind)

Comment: Are you leaving it in the US or taking it home (possibly in a computer system, or loose)?

Comment: The OP asks about bringing the item **from India** and **to the USA**, not the reverse.

Answer (score 5):

As a passenger of Indian origin (provided you have the appropriate proof (which is usually an [OCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overseas_Citizenship_of_India) card)), you have a duty-free import limit of [`50000 INR`](https://www.cbic.gov.in/resources/htdocs-cbec/guide_for_travellers/GUIDE_FOR_TRAVELLERS_v5.pdf) which is around `612 USD` (on 26 November 2022)

Assuming the rates don't change, you can bring the CPU without paying duties

Comment: Provided OP does not bring anything else that would make them exceed the limit of course.

Comment: The original question asked about bringing the CPU **from India** and **to the USA**.

Answer (score 1):

**From** India **to** the USA as a US citizen, I would assume there would be no issue in bringing in a single CPU to the USA.

It's relatively cheap, it's small, it's harmless.

People have been traveling with computers parts (for example expensive graphic cards) for ages in hand luggage.

Obviously if you have a bag full of i9-13900k some questions will probably be asked.